# is there a module for status updates in drupal 7

Tags: users

I am looking for a module that will allow users on my site to post status updates similar to Facebook and twitter. Or is there a way to configure the heartbeat module to allow users to post status updates? i am using the zen sub-theme in drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somthing along the lines of [statuses](https://drupal.org/project/statuses)?  It doesn't have a stable release yet, so is DEFINITELY not ready for production.  I've not used Heartbeat, so I can't help any more than that I'm afraid :(

Comment: thank you, i guess i'll have to wait for a stable release :)

Answer (score 1):

The 7.x Statuses module looks like it may work ok in certain circumstances. It doesn't yet work with Drupal 7 Rules or Drupal 7 Flag modules.

I would recommend trying it out and seeing what it can and can't do for you.

It doesn't, for instance interact with UserRelations so that you can start to "follow" or "friend" people.

Comment: Now we got the beta release.